# iPhone 6 GPS problem on Pokemon Go

Tags: iphone, battery, geolocation, gps

Recently when I'm playing Pokemon Go I get a message saying I don't have a GPS signal. Some people told me it could happen because the battery is pushing on the GPS component in the iPhone 6 model.

Is this a known problem? Do I need to replace the battery?

Comment: Does this happen in one location or does it happen everywhere? Can other apps that use the GPS, like Maps, function properly? Are you using your iPhone 6 in a city or rural environment? Are you in a building or outside?

Comment: it just happen sometimes, Im playing on a city. the other GPS apps work fine. when I give my phone a little strike it suddenly find my location while im playing so Im thinking it could be a hardware problem.. but its still strange cuz the other GPS apps is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have wi-fi switched on if you don't already. It doesn't need to be connected to an access point.

For some reason I get the GPS error even with a good GPS fix if I have my wi-fi switched off.

Comment: thank you i didn't thought about it actually!